# How do I Execute Terraform Actions Without the Interactive Prompt?

Tags: terraform

How am I able to execute the following command:

```sh
terraform apply

#=>

. . .

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value:
```

**without** the interactive prompt that follows?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```sh
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#auto-approve

Comment: I use more short with bash "alias tfaa='terraform apply -auto-approve'"

Answer (score -6):

Here's an example of using auto-approve with a saved plan.

**WARNING: This is a DESTROY plan, do not just copy it.**

```
$ terraform plan -destroy -out=tfplan -input=false -lock=false
(details omitted)

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Saved the plan to: tfplan
```

To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply: `terraform apply "tfplan"`

```
$ terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve -lock=false tfplan
(details omitted)

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 2 destroyed.
```